# Dealing with large overlapping sets of data - updating just the delta

Tags: mysql

My Python application generates a CSV file containing a few hundred unique records, one unique row per line. It runs hourly and very often the data remains the same from one run to another. If there are changes, then they are small, e.g.

- one record removed.
- a few new records added.
- occasional update to an existing record.

Each record is just four simple fields (name, date, id, description), and there will be no more than 10,000 records by the time the project is at maximum, so it can all be contained in a single table.

What the best way to merge changes into the table?

A few approaches I'm considering are:
1) empty the table and re-populate on each run.
2) write the latest data to a staging table and run a DB job to merge the changes into the main table.
3) read the existing table data into my python script, collect the new data, find the differences, run multiple 'CRUD' operations to apply the changes one by one

Can anyone suggest a better way?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in the following way:

1. Load the new CSV file into a second table.
2. DELETE rows in the main table that are missing from the second table:

   ```
   DELETE m FROM main_table AS m
   LEFT OUTER JOIN new_table AS t ON m.id = t.id
   WHERE t.id IS NULL;
   ```
3. Use INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to update rows that need to be updated. This becomes a no-op on each row that already contains the same values.

   ```
   INSERT INTO main_table (id, name, date, description)
     SELECT id, name, date, description FROM new_table
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
     name = VALUES(name), date = VALUES(date), description = VALUES(description);
   ```
4. Drop the second table once you're done with it.

This is assuming `id` is the primary key and you have no other UNIQUE KEY in the table.

Given a data set size of 10,000 rows, this should be quick enough to do it in one batch. Once the data set gets 10x larger, you may have to reconsider the solution, for example do batches of 10,000 rows at a time.